# Is there a way to compare two UIStoryboard objects?

Tags: objective-c, xcode, storyboard

I was wondering is there a way to compare two UIStoryboard objects?

By using the following code, I am not getting a true boolean why??? Is there are way to compare two UIStoryboard type objects??

```
if ([[UIApplication sharedApplication].keyWindow.rootViewController.presentedViewController.storyboard isEqual:[UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"ExampleStoryboard" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]]]) {

    NSLog(@"NOT TRUE HERE????")
}
```

Comment: you are comparing object with storyBord instance. it's not possible.

Comment: I know i know... Is there a way to check if presented view controller's storyboard is the storyboard I am looking for? I do not know if my question is confusing or... :) Thx anyways

Comment: first thing you want know this controller is whether from this storyboard or other. let me know iif i am right.

Comment: Comparing storyboards like this shouldn't be necessary. Can you explain what you are trying to achieve? What happens inside your conditional?

Comment: Thx for help, found another solution :)